# Set timezone for particular chart using highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a requirement to show different charts with different timezone on same page using highcharts.

**Note:** I konw highcharts supports global timezone offset but not for individual chart. So I can't use global options for showing graph in different timezone.

Comment: Maybe better is disable timezones then convert each data (per each chart) to timezone? I mean add timeoffset value to each point, manually?